# $U_{n+1} = a * U_n * (1-U_n)$ with : $3<a<3.6$ What are some values of $a$ such that $U_n$ changes its periodicity?

Tags: sequences-and-series, periodic-functions

$$U_{n+1} = a \cdot U_n \cdot (1-U_n) = a \cdot U_n - a \cdot (U_n)^2$$

with : $$3<a<3.6$$

What are some values of $a$ such that $U_n$ changes its periodicity?

I've computed $U_n$ for many different values of $a$, but $U_n$ always has a period of $2$.

For example here with $a=3.3$ :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Find a book that has this diagram:

[image: ligistic]

In fact, $3.3$ is in the period $2$ region.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feigenbaum_constants) is a table, period-doublings at:

$3, 3.4494897, 3.5440903, 3.5644073, 3.5687594, 3.5696916, \dots$